# OpenNLP HeadRules

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, opennlp

I'm trying to train a parser for a new model using the openNLP tutorial http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/opennlp/index.php?title=Parser#Training . The only problem is that is requires a head_rules file. I can't seem to find any information anywhere on generating this file and the the only link to a head_rules file can be found here:
http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models/english/parser/head_rules but I can't make sense of it. Does anyone know how to generate this from  training data?

Answer (score 1):

This is the head rules file.
Create a textfile under parser director. copy the head rules text into it. Remove the txt extension of the file. Name the file head_rules

http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models/english/parser/head_rules